# DSolve: the right way of adding solutions

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to add the solution of two differential equations:

```
F[t] = (DSolve[.1*y''[t] + .5*y'[t] + .2*y[t] == UnitStep[t], 
y[t], t] + DSolve[.2*y''[t] + .5*y'[t] + .2*y[t] == UnitStep[t], y[t], t])
```

But, this is clearly not the right way, this is what I get:

```
{{(y[t] -> 
 1. E^(-2. t) C[1] + 
  1. E^(-0.5 t)
    C[2] + (5. + 1.66667 E^(-2. t) - 6.66667 E^(-0.5 t)) UnitStep[
    t]) + (y[t] -> 
 1. E^(-4.56155 t) C[1] + 
  1. E^(-0.438447 t)
    C[2] + (5. + 0.531695 E^(-4.56155 t) - 
     5.5317 E^(-0.438447 t)) UnitStep[t])}}
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: If the code you show is how you would like to deal with DEs and their solutions, then I would suggest replacing `DSolve` with `DSolveValue`.  (OTOH, the combined solution has four independent parameters, but the code produces only two, `C[1]` and `C[2]`.)

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that each equation has independent constants of integration (I suppose), `C[1]`, `C[2]`, etc.  These parameters need to be regenerated and numbered independently.  The function `regenParam` will do that.

```
ClearAll[regenParam];
(* regenerate parameters to be successive; default parameter is C[k] *)
regenParam[p_: C][s_List] := Module[{n = 0},
  With[{params = DeleteDuplicates@Cases[#, _C, Infinity]},
     n += Length@params;
     # /. Thread[params -> Table[C[k], {k, n - Length@params + 1, n}]]
     ] & /@ s
  ];
```

We can then merge the solutions with `Total`:

```
Merge[Total]@ regenParam[]@
  {DSolve[.1*y''[t] + .5*y'[t] + .2*y[t] == UnitStep[t], y[t], t],
   DSolve[.2*y''[t] + .5*y'[t] + .2*y[t] == UnitStep[t], y[t], t]}
(*
<|y[t] -> 
  E^(-4.56155 t) C[1] + E^(-0.438447 t) C[2] + E^(-2. t) C[3] + 
   E^(-0.5 t) C[4] - 
   1.66667 E^(-2.5 t) (-1. E^(0.5 t) UnitStep[t] + 
      1. 2.71828^(2. t) E^(0.5 t) UnitStep[t] + 
      4. E^(2. t) UnitStep[t] - 
      4. 2.71828^(0.5 t) E^(2. t) UnitStep[t]) - 
   0.531695 E^(-5. t) (-1. E^(0.438447 t) UnitStep[t] + 
      1. 2.71828^(4.56155 t) E^(0.438447 t) UnitStep[t] + 
      10.4039 E^(4.56155 t) UnitStep[t] - 
      10.4039 2.71828^(0.438447 t) E^(4.56155 t) UnitStep[t])|>
*)
```

---

With a little work, one can extend this to `Function` solutions return by `DSolve[system, y, t]`. We have to write a function to total a list of functions.

```
functionTotal[s : {Verbatim[Function][{x_}, _] ..}] :=  (* Works on DSolve solutions *)
  Replace[Total[s[[All, 2]]], e_ :> Function @@ {{x}, e}]

functionTotal[s : {Verbatim[Function][{x_}, _] ..}] :=  (* Holds the Function bodies *)
  ReplacePart[
   Replace[
    Join @@ (Drop[#, 1] & /@ Hold @@@ s), 
    e_ :> Function @@ Hold[{x}, e]],
   {2, 0} -> Plus];
```

It works in the same way with `Merge` as `Total`:

```
Merge[functionTotal]@ regenParam[]@
  {DSolve[.1*y''[t] + .5*y'[t] + .2*y[t] == UnitStep[t], y, t],
   DSolve[.2*y''[t] + .5*y'[t] + .2*y[t] == UnitStep[t], y, t]}
(*
<|y -> Function[{t}, (E^(-4.56155 t) C[1] + E^(-0.438447 t) C[2] - 
      0.531695 E^(-5. t) (-1. E^(0.438447 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1. 2.71828^(4.56155 t) E^(0.438447 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         10.4039 E^(4.56155 t) UnitStep[t] - 
         10.4039 2.71828^(0.438447 t) E^(4.56155 t)
           UnitStep[t])) + (E^(-2. t) C[3] + E^(-0.5 t) C[4] - 
      1.66667 E^(-2.5 t) (-1. E^(0.5 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         1. 2.71828^(2. t) E^(0.5 t) UnitStep[t] + 
         4. E^(2. t) UnitStep[t] - 
         4. 2.71828^(0.5 t) E^(2. t) UnitStep[t]))]|>
*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following solved my problem:

```
FullSimplify[(y[t] /. 
First @ DSolve[.1*y''[t] + .5*y'[t] + .2*y[t] == UnitStep[t], 
  y[t], t]) + (g[t] /. 
First @DSolve[.2*g''[t] + .5*g'[t] + .2*g[t] == UnitStep[t], g[t],
   t])]
```

Ideas are welcome if there is a better solution, as I'm new to Mathematica.